# using US letter within an ACM paper

Tags: paper-size, acm

```
\documentclass{sig-alternate}
```

This previous line leads to a dimension 595 x 841 (according to pdf information).

```
\pdfpagewidth=8.5in
\pdfpageheight=11in
```

Those lines enabling another dimension, 612 × 792, which was required.
Are there other possibilities to ensure 8.5x11 in?

Comment: The `sig-alternate` class doesn't use `\paperwidth` or `\paperheight`, nor `\pdfpagewidth` and `\pdfpageheight`. Just set the two parameters and you're done. How the type block is placed on the page is another matter.

Answer (score 15):

Class `sig-alternate` does not set the driver dependent paper size. Therefore you get the default that is configured for pdfTeX, in your case A4. Also LaTeX's `\paperwidth` and `\paperheight` are not set (see egreg's comment).

If `\paperwidth` and `\paperheight` are set correctly, then package `geometry` can do the driver dependent part (e.g. setting `\pdfpagewidth` and `\pdfpageheight` for pdfTeX; `\special{papersize=...,...}` for dvips; …). Option `pass` lets the page layout settings unchanged. Option `showframe` displays the page layout.

```
\documentclass{sig-alternate}

% Set letter paper size:
\setlength{\paperheight}{11in}
\setlength{\paperwidth}{8.5in}
\usepackage[
  pass,% keep layout unchanged 
  % showframe,% show the layout
]{geometry}

\begin{document}
  \noindent Hello World 
\end{document}
```

PDF paper size: `8.50 x 11.0 in`
Result with `showframe`:

> [image: Result]